Python Nesting Async and Sync Context Manager
I was wondering when using mixed ContextManager (async and sync) in Python, is there any standard to say if async should be inside sync, or vice versa? Maybe it depends on what the scenario is, is there best practice to say when async should be inside sync or sync inside async?
put async within the sync cm:
with sync_cm as scm:
    async with async_cm as acm:
       ...

put sync within the async cm:
async with async_cm as acm:
    with sync_cm as scm:
        ...


It depends on the order in which you want the respective enter and exit methods to be executed. There is no general rule.

If they start and end at the same time - there is no standard for that. It only matters if either of context (__exit__ and __aexit__) takes significantly longer time to execute. E.g. closing file is much more faster, than safely closing database connection. Having database acm and file scm, you would prefer closing file first (so file scm should be inside database acm) to stop blocking file for read by others earlier

got it, thanks @sudden_appearance, i think my scenario is similar to the one you mentioned, where i am downloading a file, while writing to a file
